Searching for a manga where the mc is strong because he was trained by S class individuals
This manga takes place in a fantasy world where the protagonist has been raised and trained from birth by a group of elite S-Class party members, the most powerful individuals in the land. Among them, one of his teachers, who is strikingly beautiful, often flirts with him. The protagonist is incredibly strong, and it's revealed that part of his training involved his teacher playfully poisoning him to toughen him up. Now, he works as an adventurer.
its not that older guy who died multiple times...

Hi, I see you deleted the previous version of this question and reposted it.  That's really not necessary; if you have additional details you wish to add to your question you should just [edit] it.

You also seem to have deleted info that was in the earlier version of the question, including at least one Manga that you've already identified as not being the correct answer - "It's not the The Ossan Newbie Adventurer, the protagonist is younger here."

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

@Valorum thanks that is very helpful
